# symfony2 - how to switch from "dev" to "prod"?

Tags: php, symfony

I downloaded symfony2 and I am able to run it starting from app_dev.php.

But when I start from app.php, then I get an error page 404.

app.php though is of course there and it gets executed.

The error happens apparently somewhere after the last line of code in app.php:

```
$kernel->handle(Request::createFromGlobals())->send();
```

I guess there is a switch somewhere I have to configure.

**EDIT**:

As suggested by GeLo I added the routing for the production version to app/config/routing.yml.

```
_welcome:
    resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:     /
```

I created src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml with content:

```
bla:
    pattern: /
    defaults: {_controller:AcmeDemoBundle:Demo:index}
```

In `DemoController::indexAction()` I placed a `die(__FILE__)`;

nothing; I still get 404 from app.php !?

**EDIT regarding the answer:**

```
./app/console --env=prod cache:clear
```

did the trick. mind the env-parameter.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

By default, Symfony 2 is delivered with a demo bundle which is just accessible from the development environment.

The production environment doesn't contain any route, so it's normal you get a 404 error page.

EDIT :

Are you sure your bundle is enable in the AppKernel.php ?

If yes, clear the cache with the following command : `./app/console cache:clear`

Check if the route is enable with the following command : `./app/console router:debug`

Comment: oh ... I didn't check that. I guessed both setups are symmetrical except for error handling and that stuff.

Comment: Thanks again, actually I tracked it down upto this point and removed this bundle from appkernel and am using now new routing. please have look at my recent edit.

Comment: In my case, that wasn't enough. I had to edit `app/AppKernel.php` so that it does `$bundles[] = new Acme\DemoBundle\AcmeDemoBundle();` for `'prod'` environment, as suggested here: http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=36820

Answer (score 8):

Change the owner instead.
`sudo chown www-data:www-data -R app/cache`
`sudo chown www-data:www-data -R app/logs`

Thats letting the browser own the folders.
the syntax is:
`chown <USER>:<GROUP> <SWITCH> <DIRECTORY>`

Answer (score 5):

I just wanted to integrate a couple of tips for this kind of problem since I faced it nowadays with a new fresh Symfony2 installation.

As a fresh installation you normally get AppBundle under /src/AppBundle together with AcmeDemoBundle under /src/Acme/DemoBundle

If you want to run AcmeDemoBundle on app_dev and, in the meanwhile, have an application ( i.e. AppBundle provided with fresh installation ) on app.php ( and avoid 404 ) you can also do something like that:

in **/app/config/routing_dev.yml** comment the following rows ( if you have them ):

```
_main:
    resource: routing.yml
```

in **/app/config/routing.yml** add a new route ( if you don't have )

```
index:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Default:index }
```

then empty cache like already advised by the others and test the application on

---

1) http:// your_application_path/web/

---

2) http:// your_application_path/web/app_dev.php

If everything is fine on the first one you should get a white page with a string "Homepage."
( to edit this one go in /app/Resources/views/default/index.html.twig...
Layout for this one is base.html.twig ) and, on the second one you should get the DemoBundle provided by Symfony2.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it with just letting the web-server account (i.e. 'master-chef' own the /Symfony2/app/cache/prod directory. The command as below:

```
$sudo chown master-chef -R /var/www/Symfony2/app/cache/prod
```

Answer (score 0):

In your "web/app.php" file

```
 $kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
```

Change the value to "true".

```
 $kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);
```

Now you can load the application in production mode.

Comment: This is a very bad practice and isn't related to deploying an app at all.

Comment: @WouterJ Could you tell me why this is a bad practice? I'm a beginner with Symfony. :-)

Comment: @tomloprod debug shows lots of data you don't want to show your users (and potential hackers): File names, db info, detailed error mesages, dumps, etc. You can imagine running debug in prod being quite insecure :)

Comment: @WouterJ Ops, of course! I thought you mean that use `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);` for turn the application in production mode was a bad practice.

Comment: @WouterJ Because... `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);` will not show debug messages, no?

Answer (score -11):

Your problem is related to the cache of Symfony2. I had the same problems. Try this:

- `sudo php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug`
- `sudo chmod 777 -R ../sf2/` (sf2) is the main directory of my proyect

You're done.

Comment: `chmod 777 -R` really? DONT DO IT, ITS A SECURITY HAZARD.

Comment: This is suicide. At least tell him to do `chmod -R 777 app/cache app/logs` instead of the whole thing, but only for debugging in dev when nothing works.

Comment: Indeed! normally chmod 777 is for just "cache" dir ( in symfony3 under ./var/ )