# symfony Oops! An Error Occurred The server returned a "404 Not Found" on production

Tags: symfony

Be patience I'm brand new at symfony framework
if I run:

> php app/console server:run

it works fine

if I go to:

> http://myproject.com/app_dev.php

it works fine

if I go to:

> http://myproject.com

I got that error

my project.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myproject.com
    ServerAlias www.myproject.com

    DocumentRoot /home/whisher/public_html/myproject/web
    <Directory /home/whisher/public_html/myproject/web>
        # enable the .htaccess rewrites
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Can you help me, please ?

### .htaccess

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the app.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/app.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is the .htaccess in /web present ?

Comment: Yes, it is, I think it's a routing problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997543/why-is-my-symfony2-install-404ing-when-i-access-app-php but I'm totally new at symfony2 so I'm still on the code :(

Comment: Could you paste the content of your .htaccess file?

Comment: @Whisher I think your config is ok. I have test it and works like a charm with my project. Please check output of `php app/console router:debug --env=prod` command. Is there any action with "/" path? Can you access on any subpage?

Comment: php app/console router:debug --env=prod
[router] Current routes
 Name Method Scheme Host Path

Comment: @Whisher do you use annotation or yml file for routing?

Answer (score 11):

Symfony 3 FYI: the command is now:

```
php bin/console debug:router --env=prod
```

Also you need to use the following to clear the cache after updating routing.yml:

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env PROD
```

Hope this helps some people.

Answer (score 5):

Your configuration seems to be ok. I think that is not a problem. 
Try to check application routing by:

```
php app/console router:debug --env=prod
```

If the result is empty that you should check if there is any routes defined in:

```
app/config/routing.yml
```

and move product routing from routing_dev.yml to config file listed above.

Good Luck!

Comment: ok, that is another problem. Now remove from routing.yml those lines
`_wdt:

    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml"
    prefix:   /_wdt

_profiler:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml"

    prefix:   /_profiler

_configurator:
    resource: "@SensioDistributionBundle/Resources/config/routing/webconfigurator.xml"
    prefix:   /_configurator`
Above is dev config, those bundles are only loaded in dev enviroment

Comment: (comments are difficult to format ;)

Remove config for those labes : `_wdt` `_profiler` `_configurator`

Comment: https://gist.github.com/whisher/383e9044ae5a9da618d6 ouf :( but I think we're almost there :)

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was a file ownership and permissions problem with the "cache" "logs" and "sessions" directories when installing symfony in a user public_html directory. I solved it with the following commands

```
$ chmod g+w myproject/var
$ rm –rf myproject/var/cache
$ rm –rf myproject/var/logs
$ rm –rf myproject/var/sessions
$ ls -ld myproject/var
drwxrwx--- 5 whisher www-data 4096 Feb 16 16:35 var/
```

Now symfony was able to create the directories with the correct permissions and ownership.

Answer (score 1):

Try to clean prod cache, in app/cache/prod delete all files. It work for me.

Answer (score -1):

> php app/console cache:clear --env=prod