# CKEditor and Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using CKEditor in a textarea, it works perfectly on dev environment, although the debug bar doesn't appear.

When switching to the prod environment, CKEditor does not work.

Why? Maybe it has something to do with the debug bar? (as it is not appearing when I CKEditor loads)

I'm loading CKEditor this way:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't give enough information for a definitve answer. but here are some thoughts that might give you an idea what's wrong:

1) the debug bar probably doesn't appear for the dev environment b/c you didn't explicitely provide `<body>` Tags in your code.

2) maybe you forgot to [clear the cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6789950/symfony2-how-to-switch-from-dev-to-prod) before your switch to the production environment. then the cached templates aren't refreshed.

3) check the source code and see if the propper url to the js-file was generated.

Comment: The problem was related to the script tag itself, I solved it but I lost the tracking of the error. So I'm marking your answer as accepted because it is the only one, although the solution was different.

Comment: this is very generous of you ... people like you are the true heros! ;-)