# How to var_dump variables in twig templates?

Tags: debugging, twig

View layer pattern where you only present what you have been given is fine and all, but how do you know what is available? Is there a "list all defined variables" functionality in TWIG? *Is there a way to dump a variable?*

The solution I found by searching for it was to define a function where I can use my [existing php debug tools](https://github.com/alkemann/AL13/tree/master/al13_debug) by [injecting a function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#functions), but all references I have found to that includes these nice two lines of code, but nowhere is it specified where to place them. Going by the fact that they need a **$loader** variable defined, I tried /app/config/autoload.php but the $loader there was the wrong kind. *Where do I place the php code for adding a twig function?*

Answer (score 285, accepted):

As of Twig 1.5, the correct answer is to use the dump function. [It is fully documented in the Twig documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/functions/dump.html). [Here is the documentation to enable this inside Symfony.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html)

```
{{ dump(user) }}
```

Comment: BTW, be careful when dumping objects with relational mapping

Comment: When I use `{{ dump() }}` to dump all variables, It return a blank page. Is there any other way to dump a variable ?

Comment: I'm using latest version of Symfony 2.5, and have the config.yml and config_dev.yml setup and debug mode turned on when loading the kernel for the dev environment. I've tried the other manual methods mentioned by Morland below. Either way, I also get a blank page when dump is used. And no dump.

Comment: If you get a blank page with and without the `dump`, obviously the `dump` isn't the problem. I would suggest posting a new question if you can't figure it out otherwise.

Comment: @JerryPham Yes, this seems to be a problem. I get a Varnish error when I try to use `{{ dump() }}`, makes no difference turning Varnish off either.

Comment: I get the following error: ` Twig_Error_Syntax -  Unknown "dump" function`

Comment: You have to enable dump. See http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html for more information.

Comment: strangely, the official symfony's doc still say two ways exists : 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html#debugbundle-and-twig-integration _{% dump foo.bar %} is the way to go when [...]_

Comment: A much better approach to look for your full layer of data from twig is described on this link:  [how-to-retrieve-all-variables-from-a-twig-template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12799094/how-to-retrieve-all-variables-from-a-twig-template)   The response that worked for me is `<script>console.log({{ _context | json_encode | raw }});</script>`. Hope this can help

Comment: if `dump()` in Twig is just a blank screen check your server error logs, it's often a memory exhausted issue

Answer (score 50):

If you are in an environment where you can't use the `dump` function (ex: opencart), you can try:

```
{{ my_variable | json_encode(constant('JSON_PRETTY_PRINT')) }}
```

Answer (score 30):

You can use the `debug` tag, which is documented [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/debug.html).

```
{% debug expression.varname %}
```

Edit: As of Twig 1.5, this has been deprecated and replaced with the new `dump` function (note, it's now a function and no longer a tag). See also: The accepted answer above.

Comment: If you get a error saying `Unknown tag name "debug"`, extend your configuration (either in the global `config.yml` or `config_dev.yml`) as described here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/455#issuecomment-1884861

Comment: This method is deprecated as of Twig 1.5.

Comment: Added a deprecation note to the answer.

Answer (score 17):

So I got it working, partly a bit hackish:

1. Set `twig: debug: 1` in `app/config/config.yml`
2. Add this to config_dev.yml

   ```
   services:
       debug.twig.extension:
           class: Twig_Extensions_Extension_Debug
           tags: [{ name: 'twig.extension' }]
   ```
3. `sudo rm -fr app/cache/dev`
4. To use my own debug function instead of `print_r()`, I opened `vendor/twig-extensions/lib/Twig/Extensions/Node/Debug.php` and changed `print_r(` to `d(`

PS. I would still like to know how/where to grab the $twig environment to add filters and extensions.

Comment: btw: for clearing the cache you can use the console tool (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6789950/symfony2-how-to-switch-from-dev-to-prod)

Comment: is there any advantage to do that?

Comment: it's more straightforward ... if you don't know the console tool, I recommend you check it out

Comment: You shouldn't have to set `twig: debug: 1` because it's inheriting this information from your front controller's environment. Otherwise you could end up in uninentionally outputting debug information in your prod environment. As long as you are working in the dev environment it is enabled by default and it's disabled in your prod environment.

Comment: This is outdated as of Twig 1.5. See other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10080404/107768

Comment: probably something has changed in Twig folders structure, 'Twig_Extensions_Extension_Debug' didn't work for me but I've found this class in another Twig lib folder and 'Twig_Extension_Debug' does the job

Answer (score 15):

If you are using Twig in your application as a **component** you can do this:

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    'autoescape' => false
));

$twig->addFilter('var_dump', new Twig_Filter_Function('var_dump'));
```

Then in your templates:

```
{{ my_variable | var_dump }}
```

Comment: Where to place/replace those `$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(...` ?

Answer (score 7):

Dump all custom variables:

```
<h1>Variables passed to the view:</h1>
{% for key, value in _context %}
    {% if key starts with '_' %}
    {% else %}
        <pre style="background: #eee">{{ key }}</pre>
        {{ dump(value) }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

You can use my plugin which will do that for you (an will nicely format the output):

[Twig Dump Bar](https://github.com/caderek/twig-dump-bar)

Comment: nice snippet. thank you. this works for me if i replace dump(value) with value | var_dump

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Twig as a standalone component here's some example of how to enable debugging as it's unlikely the **dump(variable)** function will work straight out of the box

## Standalone

This was found on the link provided by icode4food

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    'debug' => true,
    // ...
));
$twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_Debug());
```

## Silex

```
$app->register(new \Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
    'debug' => true,
    'twig.path' => __DIR__.'/views'
));
```

Answer (score 4):

The complete recipe here for quicker reference (note that all the steps are mandatory):

1) when instantiating Twig, pass the debug option

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment(
$loader, ['debug'=>true, 'cache'=>false, /*other options */]
);
```

2) add the debug extension

```
$twig->addExtension(new \Twig_Extension_Debug());
```

3) Use it like @Hazarapet Tunanyan pointed out

```
{{ dump(MyVar) }}
```

or

```
{{ dump() }}
```

or

```
{{ dump(MyObject.MyPropertyName) }}
```

Answer (score 3):

`{{ dump() }}` doesn't work for me. `PHP` chokes. Nesting level too deep I guess.

All you really need to `debug` Twig templates if you're using a `debugger` is an extension like [this](https://gist.github.com/3417057).

Then it's just a matter of setting a breakpoint and calling `{{ inspect() }}` wherever you need it. You get the same info as with `{{ dump() }}` but in your debugger.

Answer (score 3):

Since Symfony >= 2.6, there is a nice [VarDumper](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper/introduction.html) component, but it is not used by Twig's `dump()` function.

To overwrite it, we can create an extension:

In the following implementation, do not forget to replace namespaces.

<kbd>Fuz/AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml</kbd>

```
parameters:
   # ...
   app.twig.debug_extension.class: Fuz\AppBundle\Twig\Extension\DebugExtension

services:
   # ...
   app.twig.debug_extension:
       class: %app.twig.debug_extension.class%
       arguments: []
       tags:
           - { name: twig.extension }
```

<kbd>Fuz/AppBundle/Twig/Extension/DebugExtension.php</kbd>

```
<?php

namespace Fuz\AppBundle\Twig\Extension;

class DebugExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array (
              new \Twig_SimpleFunction('dump', array('Symfony\Component\VarDumper\VarDumper', 'dump')),
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'FuzAppBundle:Debug';
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes I was looking for this :)

Answer (score 1):

For debugging Twig templates you can use the [debug statement](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/debug.html).

[image]

There you can set the debug setting explicitely.

Comment: I get 'Unknown tag name "debug" ' with and without setting that twig.debug: true

Comment: if you are working in prod-mode you have to clear the cache first

Comment: @AlexanderMorland Hi Alex, you have to extend your configuration as described here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/455#issuecomment-1884861 to get rid of the `Unknown tag name "debug"` error.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit

```
/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Debug.php
```

and change `the var_dump()` functions to `\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump()`

Comment: Editing anything under vendor folder is highly not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

As most good PHP programmers like to use XDebug to actually step through running code and watch variables change in real-time, using `dump()` feels like a step back to the bad old days.

That's why I made a Twig Debug extension and put it on Github.

https://github.com/delboy1978uk/twig-debug

`composer require delboy1978uk/twig-debug`

Then add the extension. If you aren't using Symfony, like this:

```
<?php

use Del\Twig\DebugExtension;

/** @var $twig Twig_Environment */
$twig->addExtension(new DebugExtension());
```

If you are, like this in your services YAML config:

```
twig_debugger:
    class: Del\Twig\DebugExtension
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

Once registered, you can now do this anywhere in a twig template:

```
{{ breakpoint() }}
```

Now, you can use XDebug, execution will pause, and you can see all the properties of both the Context and the Environment.

Have fun! :-D

Answer (score 0):

you can use **dump** function and print it like this

```
{{ dump(MyVar) }}
```

but there is one nice thing too, if you don't set any argument to dump function, it will print **all variables are available**, like

```
{{ dump() }}
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but you need to make sure debug is enabled in options when instantiating Twig