# How to use dump in TWIG?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I add for template (index.html.twig) simply:

```
{{ dump(product) }}
```

and i have error:

```
The function "dump" does not exist in AcmeStoreBundle:Default:index.html.twig at line 2
```

Why this function is not enable, and how can i enable this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to var_dump variables in twig templates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317438/how-to-var-dump-variables-in-twig-templates)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need [to configure](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#debugging) the debugging extension:

```
# app/config/config.yml
services:
    acme_hello.twig.extension.debug:
        class:        Twig_Extension_Debug
        tags:
             - { name: 'twig.extension' }
```

Per the link mentioned above, Twig debugging is set to work by default in Symfony 2.5+ running Twig 1.16+, and the custom service definition is not necessary. [See this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26151553/3334390).

Comment: I don't know if these are old answers or just incomplete, but this definitely does NOT work for me. I've tried many different versions of this answer, to no avail.

Comment: @ChadwickMeyer there's a link that says all you need is to enable it in the config `twig: debug: true`

Comment: Thanks. I had done that and it didn't work. But I also upgraded from Symfony 2.4 to 2.5 and ran `composer update` (which upgraded from Twig 1.15 to 1.16 and now it's working. So who knows...

Comment: And for the record, I deleted the custom config you mention in this answer, since the link you reference says Twig debug enabled in dev environment by default.

Comment: @ChadwickMeyer don't know why your edit was rejected. Added your link and upvoted your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

When you configure it like @meze said, you can display all custom variables:

```
<h1>Variables passed to the view:</h1>
{% for key, value in _context %}
    {% if key starts with '_' %}
    {% else %}
        <pre style="background: #eee">{{ key }}</pre>
        {{ dump(value) }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

You can use my simple plugin to convenient inspect your variables:

[Twig Dump Bar](https://github.com/caderek/twig-dump-bar)

Answer (score 2):

***Symfony 2.7+ UPDATE:***

The DebugBundle allows greater integration of the component into the Symfony full-stack framework. It is enabled by default in the dev and test environment of the Symfony Standard Edition.

Check the [VarDumper component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html) and its [integration on Twig](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html#debugbundle-and-twig-integration).

***OLD ANSWER:***

I would like to suggest a non-native solution. You'll need a third-party bundle, but the final result will be great!

Improvements to the `dump` version:

1. all dumps are styled
2. you can provide the max nesting level to avoid memory issues with large objects
3. very useful helpers like `ldd()`, which is an alias for the classic "dump and die"
4. it has a console dumper (eg. `php app/console ladybug:dump "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request"`)
5. it provides an integration with the Symfony Profiler
6. it automatically detects Symfony, Doctrine, Twig and Silex classes, and links them to the official documentation

Here the links:

- [knpbundles](http://knpbundles.com/raulfraile/LadybugBundle)
- [github](https://github.com/raulfraile/LadybugBundle)

Comment: on Symfony 2.7+ you're probably better off with the official `VarDumper` component: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html#debugbundle-and-twig-integration