# How to debug Twig?

Tags: symfony, twig

How can I do serious debugging in Twig? I know [how to dump single variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120256/how-to-use-dump-in-twig). But what if you have no clue which template is rendering the part of the page you are looking at? Or you want to know which templates are used to render a page?

In Drupal 6/7 I can enable [the theme developer module](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer). This allows me to point and click on any part of the page and I get a list of all used templates (and much more information). Maybe I’m asking for too much or doing it the wrong way.

How can I find the template in charge of a particular part of the page? If this is too much, how can I see what templates are called by the Twig engine? Getting a trace would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The Developers toolbar (app_dev.php) should list all templates used to render your page.

Comment: I cannot find anything usefull about twig in the developer toolbar. Is there something I need to enable?

Comment: Have a look at http://fabien.potencier.org/article/66/debugging-silex-applications-just-got-funnier it shows how can you use the profiler in silex. Note that you need to depend on 2.2 for this feature.

Comment: when you open the debug toolbar, check the request tab. scroll down, you'll find a list of all sub-requests which should list all used templates.