# how to check all available variable that have been passed form controller to twig template

Tags: php, templates, twig, symfony-2.3

how to check all variable  exist

**Exp in Controller return this to pass to twig template :**

```
return $this->render('index/index.html.twig', [ 'department'=>$departments,'URILink'=>$URILink,'departmentDetail'=>$departmentDetails, 'contentCell'=>$this->mContentCell ]);
```

> then twig  template can reuse those variable by doin this

**index.html.twig:**

```
</div> {{ include ('department_list.html.twig',{'departments':department,'URILink':URILink}) }}</div>
```

**for Comparison in smarty template we can use this:**

get_template_vars() — returns assigned variable value(s)

> how to do that with same analogy in twig template? in case i want to make sure  all
>   variable have been passed correctly

Answer (score 2):

after read this
[How to retrieve all Variables from a Twig Template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12799094/how-to-retrieve-all-variables-from-a-twig-template)

i found out just simple

> {%dump%}

will look all variables passed on a template

Comment: This is very useful information, and the first time I found out about it. Make sure you don't use `dump` in your `prod` environment though. You'll get errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can include a template like this per http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#including-other-templates

```
{{ include('YourBundle:ControllerName:yourAction.html.twig', {'variableName': yourData}) }}
```

Or like this per http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html

```
{% include 'template.html' with {'foo': 'bar'} %}
```

If you want to check `variable` use function in `dev` mod:

```
{{ dump(yourVariable) }}
```

Comment: yes that is alternative syntax for passing variable but my point of question is how to check all variable that been passed, if a have a lot variable from controller to twig so I wont miss any of them

Answer (score 0):

Instead of verifying that each variable exists when you pass it, it's better practice, imho, to utilize the filter `default` in this case

```
<div>
    {{ include ('department_list.html.twig',  'departments':department|default(null),'URILink':URILink|default(null) }}
</div
```