# reuse variable as string

Tags: twig

This question maybe kind of silly but I'm a newbie for symfony anyway.
*prescenario* I pass a variable from controller into `index.html.twig` by doing this

```
 return $this->render('index/index.html.twig', [ 'department'=>$departments,'URILink'=>$URILink,'departmentDetail'=>$departmentDetails,'contentCell'=>$this->mContentCell ]);
```

After using `{% dump %}` it shows me

```
  "department" => array:3 [▶]
  "URILink" => "http://localhost/index/department/"
  "departmentDetail" => array:1 [▶]
  "contentCell" => "department.html.twig"
```

Then I need to reuse the variable `contentCell` as string in template to form syntax similar to this ;

```
<div>{{ include ('department.html.twig'),[departmentDetail:departmentDetail]</div>
```

For my first attempt I tried this,

```
<div> {{ include ({{ContentCell}}),[departmentDetail:departmentDetail]}} </div>
```

Unfortunately it showed me this error

> A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression
>   enclosed in parentheses (unexpected token "punctuation" of value "{".

Any idea how could I use the variable 
`contentCell` as string value appropriately?

Comment: In twig when you include `template` and passing with data you have to safe syntax, for example when passing data you pass as json format: `{'variableName': yourData}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> after try'n try at last I found the the trick how to do it

i take similar analogy for

```
{{dump(var)}}
```

> so attempt to do this

```
{{include (contentCell,{'departmentDetail' : departmentDetail})  }}
```

**and it work like charm :) nice**

Comment: If it works, you can accept your own  answer, such that it will move up.

Comment: nope, i already  answer my own question 2 time's  it block me to click the accept sign

Comment: Ok, I wasn't aware of that there are additional rules about self accepting answers, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
{% include contentCell  with { departmentDetail : departmentDetail} %}
```

Comment: no lucky @alessandro it give me error Unexpected token "operator" of value "~".

Comment: Try without ~ please

Comment: yes, it can include department.html.twig but on bad  side effect it breaking variable DepartmentDetail to pass

Comment: This does not break anything and is a valid answer

Answer (score 1):

Answer here [pass data to twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45528452/how-to-check-all-available-variable-that-have-been-passed-form-controller-to-twi/45528488#45528488)

You can include a template like this per:

```
{{ include('YourBundle:ControllerName:yourAction.html.twig', {'variableName': yourData}) }}
```

Or like this per http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html

```
{% include 'template.html' with {'foo': 'bar'} %}
```

Comment: nope @Imanali Mamadiev i avoid to use hard-coded template name since the logic of my code is 'no template will be showed if i didn't needed it',  thats way reuse dynamic variable