# How do we get the variables from a twig template using php?

Tags: php, twig

Is there any way to dynamically get all the variables used in a twig template by PHP?

I don't want to dump the variables or context inside the template itself. I have only the path of the template and I want to know which data I need to render the template.

I need data from the objects(I don't need only `var` but `var.x` and `var.y` as well) or other included templates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve all Variables from a Twig Template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12799094/how-to-retrieve-all-variables-from-a-twig-template)

Comment: Also some extra [reference](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/2188#issuecomment-254472707)

Comment: @DarkBee I used this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49203315/1797978 answer, I refactored it to the new version of twig but it always returns an empty array.

Comment: Did you try out the [`twig 3.0 version`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74367172/446594)? Keep in my mind those snippet of code don't delve any deeper into like `included`, `embedded`  templates, `macros` or global variables which is mentioned by Stof in the referenced github thread

Comment: @DarkBee It works but tells nothing about deeper layers like the object attributes