# how to use var_dump SAP Anywhere?

Tags: twig, sqlanywhere

I am studying SAP Anywhere .twig objects, and I want to display `collection` object's content by using [{{ dump(user) }}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317438/how-to-var-dump-variables-in-twig-templates), but it's not displaying any data. This documentation is for symphony, I wonder if SAP Anywhere has different .twig language.

Comment: Make sure you load the [dump](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html) function

Comment: i miss that part there! ^_^ tnx. where to put the function?

Comment: by the way, thats for php only, I am in SAP Anywhere.

Comment: You will need the locate the code/source where SAP loads and configures `twig`, don't know much about it myself. But the problem you don't see anything is probably because you run `twig` without `debug` on, thus it does not display errors about non-existing functions

Comment: it has no settings. It's an online e-commerce cms.

Comment: So you can't access any source files or change the `debug` mode?

Comment: no. All .twig examples out there is for php only.