# Symfony Error The server returned a 404 Not Found

Tags: windows, symfony, configuration, installation

I am new to Symfony.

I just installed Symfony 2.3.2 by following instruction given at http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html for windows.

When i open

```
http://localhost/Symfony/web/
```

then i get error given below

**Oops! An Error Occurred**

**The server returned a "404 Not Found".**

However if i run

```
http://localhost/Symfony/web/app-dev.php
```

then i get the Welcome page of Symfony.

What settings i need to change to point

```
http://localhost/Symfony/web/app-dev.php
```

by calling

```
http://localhost/Symfony/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update .htaccess in web directory like this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

/ will redirect to /app_dev.php

Comment: what will i need to do to point http://localhost/Symfony/web/app-dev.php by calling http://localhost/Symfony/

Answer (score 1):

Look here:
[symfony2 - how to switch from "dev" to "prod"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6789950/symfony2-how-to-switch-from-dev-to-prod)

You don't have to redirect to app_dev.php because it will work as soon as you create your first bundle/route.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same and my problem was dumber. 
I configured the whole Symfony project, and restarted apache for the changes to take effect, doing this (**WRONG**):

```
service apache2 stop
service apache2 start
```

which did not take effect, as I was a regular user. Had to do (**RIGHT**):

```
sudo service apache2 stop
sudo service apache2 start
```

Then my `/app_dev.php` started working and website loading