# Symfony2.5.0 fresh install - No route found for "GET /", 404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException

Tags: symfony

Hi I am new to symforny2
I have just installed symfony2 on my easyphp server. When I open web directory symfony try to open app.php. For some reason I got this output:

> ```
> No route found for "GET /"
> 404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException
> 1 linked Exception: ResourceNotFoundException »
>
> [2/2] NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /"   +
> [1/2] ResourceNotFoundException:    +
> Logs   -
> Stack Trace (Plain Text)   +
> ```

When I open app_dev.php, everything looks normal. 
Why do I get this 404 error on app.php ? Is that normal or is this a bug in symfony2.5.0
(demos in app_dev.php are working well)

Thank You for your support.
Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See one of my previous answer: [symfony2 - how to switch from "dev" to "prod"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6789950/symfony2-how-to-switch-from-dev-to-prod/6790126#6790126)

Symfony wraps multiple environment. When you access the `app.php` front controller, you're on the prod environment whereas when you access `app_dev.php`, you're on the dev environment.

Knowing that, the demo bundle shipped with the standard edition is only enable on the dev environment according to the `AppKernel`. So, it is normal you can access the demo page on the dev front controller and get a 404 on the prod front controller.

Comment: Thanks! I started to think that i did something wrong during the installation. :)