# Symfony 2 (2.3.x) Annotation Route not working

Tags: symfony, annotations, routes

I'm new on symfony and I'm following this tutorial:
http://it.siciarek.pl/docs/references/howtostart.html

At some point at the end of the installation process (after getting rid of ACME) I've created a new Bundle

```
php app/console generate:bundle --bundle-name=AgcoukMainBundle --namespace=Agcouk/MainBundle --dir=src --format=annotation --structure --no-interaction
```

my DefaultController looks like:

```
namespace Agcouk\MainBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="home")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return array();
    }
}
```

and my routing.yml (app/config/routing.yml)

```
agcouk_main:
    resource: "@AgcoukMainBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
```

Now, trying to access the page sf2/ (sf2/config.php works!) I get a 404 Error.

I've even debugged the routes via console (php app/console router:debug home) and everything looks fine to me

```
[router] Route "home"
Name         home
Path         /
Host         ANY
Scheme       ANY
Method       ANY
Class        Symfony\Component\Routing\Route
Defaults     _controller: Agcouk\MainBundle\Controller\DefaultController::indexAction
Requirements NO CUSTOM
Options      compiler_class: Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler
Path-Regex   #^/$#s
```

(I've tried even to specify the Controller file name in the routing.yml and nothing changes, even the debug gives the same result).

Any clue? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by this post:
[symfony2 - how to switch from "dev" to "prod"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6789950/symfony2-how-to-switch-from-dev-to-prod)

I've finally solved the issue. I've manually deleted the files in app/cache/dev and app/cache/prod and then I've changed the owner of the prod cache folder

`sudo chown www-data app/cache/prod`

now, pointing at my virtual host (sf2) the page is loaded with no 404 Error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use Symfony's Official Documentation... [www.symfony.com](http://www.symfony.com)

This tutorial you are following are even writing the framework's name wrong: "Symphony", so maybe is out of date or something.

And have you tried to clear your cache? `php app/console cache:clear --env=dev`

Comment: I've spent two evenings on the official documentation always ending up deleting the project, this articles look more straight forward to me and as you can see I spell the name correctly ;)

Anyway, back to the topic, yes I've cleaned the cache both via console and physically deleting the files in the folder. No luck!

Comment: I've just discovered that http://sf2/app_dev.php works (shows the sf2/src/Agcouk/MainBundle/Resources/views/Default/index.html.twig template) while app.php doesn't and it seems that app.php is called when I try to access http://sf2

Wrong settings somewhere?